# Removing Item from array in reducer not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to remove single item from cart in reducer but not it does not seems to work. itemsInCart is Updated in ADD_TO_CART but not in REMOVE_FROM_CART.

Can anyone suggest edit to my code....

I tried passing mutable/immutable params to manageItemCount()

```
function manageItemCount(allItems, newItem){
    let itemIndex = [];
    if(allItems.length > 0) {
        allItems.forEach((elem, i) => { 
            if (elem.product.id == newItem.product.id) {
                itemIndex.push(i);
            }; 
        });

        if(itemIndex.length){
            allItems.splice(itemIndex.length-1, 1);
        }
    }
    return allItems;
}

let alreadyRemovedFromCart = false;

const cartReducer = (state = {
    itemsInCart: []
}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            state = {
                ...state,
                itemsInCart: [...state.itemsInCart, action.payload]
            };
            break;
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
            state = {
                ...state,
                itemsInCart: manageItemCount(...state.itemsInCart, action.payload)
            };
            break;
    }

    return state;
}

export default cartReducer;
```

Comment: `itemsInCart: state.itemsInCart.filter(e => e.product.id !== payload.product.id)` Try to use filter for such cases

Comment: hi @errorpro i tried this but this removes all item from cart but i want to remove single item

Comment: `fn(...arr)` means `fn(arr[0], arr[1], and so on)`. You just need to copy array, not to spread it over arguments `manageItemCount([...state.itemsInCart], action.payload)`

Comment: thanks @YuryTarabanko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manageItemCount` accepts two parameters but you are spreading all the `itemsInCart` array. So it should be:

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':
  state = {
    ...state,
    itemsInCart: manageItemCount(state.itemsInCart, action.payload)
  };
  break
```

Also `manageItemCount` seems like it is doing just `.filter` on `itemsInCart`.

Comment: or `([...state.itemsInCart], action.payload)` as `manageItemCount` is mutating.

Comment: thanks man @Gabriel u saved my day... The issue was i passed mutated argument